# Why can't I declare templated type aliases inside of functions?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, c++14, template-aliases

Why can't I declare a templated type alias inside of a function?

```
#include <vector>

int main(){

    //type alias deceleration:
    template <typename T>
    using type = std::vector<T>;

    //type instantiation:
    type<int> t;

}
```

> **error:** a template declaration cannot appear at block scope

Why are we forced to put these declarations outside of block scope?

```
#include <vector>

//type alias deceleration:
template <typename T>
using type = std::vector<T>;

int main(){

    //type instantiation:
    type<int> t;
}
```

Comment: You *can* declare type aliases inside of functions. What you have there is a template alias.

Comment: @user2079303 right.  adjusted question.

Comment: Given the current answer, "The Standard says so", could you clarify if the question was "*why* was it decided to not allow this?", which is how I originally read it.

Comment: See [EWG issue 95](http://wg21.link/EWG95) and [CWG issue 822](http://wg21.link/CWG822). "EWG failed to find sufficient motivation for this extension".

Comment: So, because they "failed to find sufficient motivation" to allow it.

Comment: @BoBTFish.  Thank you.  Obviously the standard says so.  I wanted to know why the limitation existed in the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard says so.

From the C++11 Standard (emphasis mine):

> **14 Template**
>
> **2 A template-declaration can appear only as a namespace scope or class scope declaration**. In a function template declaration, the last component of the declarator-id shall not be a template-id. [ Note: That last component may be an identifier, an operator-function-id, a conversion-function-id, or a literal-operator-id. In a class template declaration, if the class name is a simple-template-id, the declaration declares a class template partial specialization (14.5.5). —end note ]